# Dynamic dropdown items to avoid empty filtered queries (django-filter)

Tags: django, django-filter

I've started using django-filter and it works absolutely great; i have this Filter that's going:
I'm filtering through my Worldfood Object, and picking through related fields with dropdown picklists.

The problem : i'd like to update the second picklist depending on what has been picked in the first.

For example say i have a Worldfood object,

- I have very general country attribute French, Italian, USA,
  Mexican... etc.
- Then a sub family that is country-specific like say per city; linked to the first with a foreign key.
- Finally the food is city specific, (so linked to a country through
  something like city__country)

With Django-filter i have two picklists, the first being the country, the second being the city.

What is the best way to have the options from the city picklist depend on the selected one from the country ? Because for now its possible to choose USA / Shanghai which gives obviously no results.

```
class WorldfoodFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model =  Worldfood
        fields = ['city__country, 'city']
```

Thanks !

PS: there are similar posts about this, but i havent found one specific to the django_filter add-on

Comment: Under the hood, django-filter actually constructs a standard django form. Any solution for django forms should apply here too.

Comment: yeah so actually i found a way to do it using JS to hide the fields that are incompatible between them (through a compatibility dictionnary); i'll post it as an answer - though imperfect